# Why does a slope in Linear Regression follow a t-distribution?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, t-distribution

The slope is a Point Estimate of the population parameter. And the t-distribution is used when the Point Estimate is *approximately* normal.

So are we using the t-distribution because we know the Point Estimate/The Slope is approx normal? If so, how?